# Solaris 10: cannot ping to/from server

Tags: routing, solaris

All,

I have a Solaris 10 server which is not reachable by IP (ie can't ping to/from the server).  I believe I have the default route setup correctly.  See below:

```
# ifconfig -a
lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
bge0: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 2
inet 192.168.62.100 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 192.168.62.255
ether 0:14:4f:b1:9b:30

# netstat -rn
Routing Table: IPv4
Destination       Gateway           Flags        Ref        Use  Interface
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ------ ---------
192.168.62.0      192.168.62.100     U           1          40   bge0
224.0.0.0         192.168.62.100     U           1           0   bge0
default           192.168.62.1       UG          1           0
127.0.0.1         127.0.0.1          UH          1           4   lo0
#

# cat /etc/defaultrouter
192.168.62.1
```

I have verified layer1 and layer 2 are up on the switchport, and that it's on the correct VLAN. I have also checked the default gateawy (192.168.62.1) is in fact reachable since I can ping it from my PC:

```
Pinging 192.168.62.1 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.62.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=254
Reply from 192.168.62.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=254
Reply from 192.168.62.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=254
Reply from 192.168.62.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=254
```

I'm at a loss as to what is wrong.  I would highly appreciated your assistance.

Thank you very much.

UPDATE1:

Don't see ARP entry for default gateway:

```
# arp -a
Net to Media Table: IPv4
Device   IP Address               Mask      Flags   Phys Addr
------ -------------------- --------------- ----- ---------------
bge0   192.168.77.1         255.255.255.255       00:17:59:01:55:50
bge0   pgw1                 255.255.255.255 SP    00:14:4f:b1:9b:30
bge0   192.168.62.53        255.255.255.255       00:1b:53:36:f5:30
bge0   224.0.0.0            240.0.0.0       SM    01:00:5e:00:00:00
```

UPDATE2:

I added a static arp entry for the default gateway but this did not help.  Please suggest the next step.

UPDATE3:

I moved the server to a different switchport and that resolved the problem.  Thanks guys for your helpful suggestions.  Peace.

Comment: Do you see any traffic if you run a snoop/tcpdump on bge0?

Comment: Do you see ARP for the gateway address?

Comment: Is ip filtering enabled?  Run ipfstat to check.

Comment: Murali, I only see ARP traffic in snoop.  Kyle, I don't see ARP entry for gateway.  I've updated the problem description with ARP table.  hurfdurf, ip filtering is not enabled.

Comment: @anurag  kohli: I have checked an S10 system I have to hand and it looks exactly like yours. Can you try connecting something else to the same switch port and cable to verify them? Is there a second NIC on the system ?

Comment: @Iain:  I connected my PC to the same switchport and had the same problem.  This means problem lies with the switch.  I ended up plugging the server into a know good port and I can happily ping.  THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked an S10 system I have to hand and it looks exactly like yours. Can you try connecting something else to the same switch port and cable to verify them? Is there a second NIC on the system ?

```
# ifconfig -a
lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
e1000g0: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 192.168.1.68 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 0:c:29:25:22:f8

# netstat -rn

Routing Table: IPv4
  Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- ---------
default              192.168.1.254        UG        1          8
192.168.1.0          192.168.1.68         U         1          3 e1000g0
224.0.0.0            192.168.1.68         U         1          0 e1000g0
127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            UH        4        127 lo0
```

Comment: I connected my PC to the same switchport and had the same problem. This means problem lies with the switch. I ended up plugging the server into a know good port and I can happily ping.